# How to swap the values from one column to another in Spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with 6 columns. Here i need to assign one column values to another column. There is a need to put the values from ROW column to ItemData Column. Here all the columns are struct type not just a string name.

```
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+--------------------+
|index|                 ROW|        Document    |ItemData           | noNamespaceSchemaLocation|                _xsi|
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+--------------------+
|    0|[1,1,1018,17.0...   |[[,2001-12-17T09:...|            [,,,,,]|      GetItemMasterSupp...|http://www.w3.org...|
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+--------------------+
```

I have tried to register the DF to temp table and then tried swapping the columns but it did not help.

```
The final output should look like this 
+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+--------------------+
|        Document   |ItemData           | noNamespaceSchemaLocation|                _xsi|
+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+--------------------+
|[[,2001-12-17T09:...|  [1,1,1018,17.0...|      GetItemMasterSupp...|http://www.w3.org...|
+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+--------------------+
```

df.printschema()
This is the schema

```
root
 |-- index: long (nullable = false)
 |-- ROW: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- CLTRP: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- CORP: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- CORP_ITEM_CD: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- CTIV: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- CTLFAC: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- CTLI: long (nullable = true)
 |-- DocData: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Document: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- AltementID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Creat: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- DataClasion: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- BusinessSeel: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- DataCLevel: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- PCaInd: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- PHtaInd: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- PPnd: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- DocumentAction: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ActionTypeCd: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- RecordTypeCd: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ItemData: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- CorpCd: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- CorId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- DepId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- DisrId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- DivId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- WarId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _noNamespaceSchemaLocation: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _xsi: string (nullable = true)
```

**

- Edit 1:

**
Updated to show dataframe creation

```
//XML Data Reader
    val supData="Input_File/SCI_Input.xml"
    val booksFileTag1 = "ROWSET"   

    val dataDF = (new XmlReader()).withRowTag(booksFileTag1).xmlFile(sqlContext, supplyData).toDF()

    val dataFrame1 = dataDF.withColumn("index",monotonically_increasing_id())   

// XML Schema Reader
val suppySchema="Input_File/Supply_sample.xml"
val booksFileTag = "GetItemMaster"      

val schemaDf = (new XmlReader()).withRowTag(booksFileTag).xmlFile(sqlContext, suppySchema).toDF()

val dataFrame2 = schemaDf.withColumn("index",monotonically_increasing_id())

val finalDf = dataFrame1.join(dataFrame2,"index")

finalDf.show()



 Output for reference for @JXC
 |-- ItemData: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- CLTRP: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- CORP: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- CORP_ITEM_CD: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- CTIV: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- CTLFAC: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- CTLI: long (nullable = true)
```

Comment: `new_df = df.selectExpr('Document', 'ROW AS ItemData', 'noNamespaceSchemaLocation', '_xsi')`

Comment: @user1638818- could you also post create statement for your dataframe?

Comment: @vikrantrana -- Edited my question with dataframe creation part

Comment: @jxc -- Thanks for the answer i tried to do what you advised but there is a problem with this method, If i select 'ROW' AS ItemData' then the schema of my Item data also gets changed to that of ROW column which i don't want. I need to have schema of ItemData as showed in my question (df.printschema()) only the values should move to ItemData column. After trying the above code the schema looks like this for ItemData (Showed in the original question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply rename Row column as ItemData and then drop old ItemData column.

You can various ways of renaming columns :-
https://sparkbyexamples.com/rename-a-column-on-spark-dataframes/

Comment: These examples really helped me to get what i was looking for. Thanks for suggesting the link. I appreciate

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df = df.withColumn("ItemData", F.col("ROW")).drop("ROW")
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, swapping is not same as renaming (which is already answered here).

If you are looking to swap two column's values, say `col_A` and `col_B`, do this:

```
df.withColumn("col_A_", 'col_B)
  .withColumn("col_B", 'col_A)
  .withColumn("col_A", "col_A_")
  .drop('col_A_)
```